# Why does encodingWithCoder take so long with a UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, encode, nscoding

So I have a class called "Picture", it is similar to UIImage except it also contains a BOOL for another use...

In my app, I have it save and retrieve the data later using NSCoding. I have gotten it "working" with what I want, but it takes in excess of 5 seconds to encode each time. This will be extremely annoying to users and I am trying to figure out what is causing it. I may be doing something silly or naive but some guidance would be appreciated.

This is the relevant part of the main file for Picture

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
[encoder encodeObject:image forKey:@"imageKey"];
[encoder encodeBool:isDefault forKey:@"isDefaultKey"];
NSLog(@"Encoding Picture");
}
```

Side note: Decoding works as expected, it is only encoding that is troublesome.

**Would using NSData be faster without degrading image quality? If so, how would I use NSData here for both encoding and decoding?** Thank You!